# SDL_KEYDOWN and key recognition not working properly

Tags: c++, input, sdl

In my project I am having trouble getting a simple switch statement to work for SDL input. Here is the example:

```
SDL_Event event;

SDL_PollEvent(&event);


if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
{

    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_a: m_x -= 30;
            break;
    case SDLK_d: m_x += 30;
            break;
    case SDLK_w: m_y -= 30;
            break;
    case SDLK_s: m_y += 30;
            break;
    }
}
```

When I run this, first off it seems SDL_KEYDOWN isn't being recognized. Nor are my cases. So I switched the code to:

```
SDL_Event event;

SDL_PollEvent(&event);


if (event.type == 771)
{

    switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
    {
    case SDLK_a: m_x -= 30;
            break;
    case SDLK_d: m_x += 30;
            break;
    case SDLK_w: m_y -= 30;
            break;
    case SDLK_s: m_y += 30;
            break;
    default: m_y += 1;
    }
}
```

This causes the default case to run when I hold or press any key, so my object moves according to m_y += 1. If I remove the default case and try pressing w,a,s, or d, nothing happens. If i keep m_y += 1, but use SDL_KEYDOWN instead of 771, nothing happens. (I got the 771 code by printing the event.type whenever a key is being pressed).

Comment: are you sure you are #include-ing SDL.h ?

Answer (score 4):

You call `SDL_PollEvent()` only once, so it gives the event which occurred first which might not be `SDL_KEYDOWN`.
You must make a `main` loop to handle your events:

```
SDL_Event event;
bool quit=false;    
while(!quit)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)
    {
        if(event.type==SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
             ....
        }
        else if(event.type==SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit=true;
        }
    }
}
```

This loop takes care of the events which you don't care about(for e.g. `MOUSEMOTION`).

And you can also use `switch` with `event.type` if you are going to handle many different types of events.