# SDL_KEYDOWN not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, input, sdl

I have made a class for keyboard input in my C++ program with SDL. But for some reason SDL_KEYDOWN doesn't return what I would think. Here is my input class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Input.h"
using namespace std;
string Input::check_event() {
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type){
        case SDL_QUIT:
            return "quit";

        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch(event.key.keysym.sym){
            case SDLK_w:
                return "w";
            case SDLK_a:
                return "a";
            case SDLK_s:
                return "s";
            case SDLK_d:
                return "d";
            }

        }

    }
    return "null";
}
```

In my main function I cout input.check_event(); on a loop, but even when I press a key it still outputs "null".

Comment: "SDL_KEYDOWN doesn't return what I would think" - well, what do you think it should return, and what does it return?

Comment: It should return "w", "a", "s", or "d", depending on what i input. Instead it ignores the input and returns the default "null".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664139/sdl-keydown-and-key-recognition-not-working-properly